# Mongodb : find max and distinct

Tags: mongodb

In MongoDB I have some documents such as these :

```
{type:'a', ts:123, foo:'bar'}
{type:'a', ts:456, foo:'baz'}
{type:'a', ts:789, foo:'whee'}
{type:'b', ts:123, foo:'jingle'}
{type:'b', ts:456, foo:'bells'}
{type:'b', ts:789, foo:'yeehaaw'}
```

I would like to find the documents which have the max ts value for each type.
Is it possible to do that with a disngle query ? 
I've looked at distinct but apparently it only returns the disting 'type' values.
So I guess I would need a combination of $max alongside distinct ... 
But I can't figure the proper way.

Thanks

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/

Comment: It is an easy query. You can use aggregation framework. db.collectionName.aggregate([{$group:{_id:"$type",maxtsvalue:{$max:"$ts"}}}]);